# In GNU Make, output of function call is being treated as a separate line to be executed by the shell

Tags: gnu-make

I have defined the following function in a GNU Make file:

```sh
define comma-seperated
    $(shell printf '$(foreach name,$(1),$(name),)' | head -c -1)
end
```

And you would use it like this:

```sh
names := John Paul George Ringo
.PHONY: test
test:
   @echo Hey $(call comma-sepperated, "$(names)")
```

but It's outputting as:

```sh
Hey
"John,Paul,George,Ringo"
```

and generating an error:

```sh
/bin/sh: John,Paul,George,Ringo: command not found
make: *** [Makefile: test] Error 127
```

Why is the output of the function call being moved to a separate line, and why is the shell trying to then execute it as a command?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the failure you describe given the makefile you provide here.  It works fine for me so there must be something about your real environment you haven't shown us, and that thing is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I can't reproduce this.  Also, your makefile adds spaces after the commas while your example output doesn't have these, so something is clearly different.  Please try to ensure that your questions use the exact example code and show the exact output.

However, a `define` variable is allowed to contain newlines and if it does, those newlines are preserved and interpreted as newlines in any recipe it is expanded in.  For example you can create an entire recipe inside a `define`, including multiple lines, then use it in a rule and it will work as expected.
So, my suspicion is that in your real version there's an initial newline in the expansion.

I don't see any good reason to use such a complex method for this, though: a difficult-to-understand combination of call, shell, printf, head, etc.  It's much simpler to do all of this within make.

Here's one way to do it:

```
EMPTY :=
SPACE := $(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
COMMA := ,

comma-separated = $(subst $(SPACE),$(COMMA),$(strip $(1)))

names := John Paul George Ringo
.PHONY: test
test:
        @echo Hey $(call comma-separated,$(names))
```

Comment: I updated `comma-separated` to be more like how you have it and that fixed it, but I only did that because I understood from your post about the new line thing. Also The reason I did it the way I did was because for some strange reason it didn't occur to me to just substitute `"  "` for `", "` so also thank you for that too.